# CollectionViewSource to be bind to a property in a singleton

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, singleton, collectionviewsource

I have such a singleton class

```
public class Sample
{
    private static readonly Lazy<Sample> lazy =
    new Lazy<Sample>(() => new Sample());

    private ObservableCollection<SampleGroup> _groups;

    public ObservableCollection<SampleGroup> Groups
    {
        get { return _groups; }
    }
```

}

I bind the `Groups` property to a `ListView` by this,

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <!-- Data Source For Binding-->
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="SampleGroups" Source="{Binding Groups}" />
 </Window.Resources>
 ...
 <ListView x:Name="GroupNameListView" 
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SampleGroups}}"
                                  SelectedIndex="0"  SelectionChanged="GroupNameListView_SelectionChanged" >
  ....
```

In order to make this work, I need to put `this.DataContext= Sample.Instance` in the code behind.

Is that possible that I can specify this `DataContext` in the `<Window.Resources>` part,?because I would like to add another `CollectionViewSource` which has a different `DataContext` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly bind the singleton class as mentioned below.

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="SampleGroups" Source="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Sample.Instance}, Path=Groups}" />
```